# Cannot change php version in apache on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I setup a new LAMP stack on Ubuntu 16.04 via Virtualmin. I needed php5, so I added the ondrej repo (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php) and installed the packages I needed. Then I enabled php5 on apache (sudo a2enmod php5.6).

Usually when I do this I can change the php verion in my apache vhost configuration files.

Now here is the twist, apache will only run php5.6 now. If I disable it, uninstall it, etc, it just downloads the php files. I have combed over ever configration file and I cannot find where php7.0 is treated any differently that php5.6.

Also, it seems to be running under www-data instead of the virtual server owner regardless of the configurations.

I have trued to compare every configuration file (/etc/apache2) to a working setup on a different server, but I cannot find a significant difference.

Any intuition on this is appreciated.